# conditional union

Tags: sql, union, conditional-statements

Let's say I have three subqueries combined in a UNION.

```
select * from (
    select nr, pos, '1' from foo
    union all
    select nr, pos, '2' from bar
    union all
    select nr, pos, '3' from foobar
)
```

What I need is a result that returns rows from `foobar`
only if the `nr` value was not returned by the first sub-query (from `foo`).

The `nr` column has to be the only condition, not the entire row,
so a UNION wouldn't help. Am I right?

Sorry I don't know how to explain this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ranking functions are supported by the SQL product you are using, you could try the following:

```
SELECT nr, pos, src
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY nr ORDER BY src) AS rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT nr, pos, '1' AS src FROM foo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nr, pos, '3' AS src FROM foobar
  ) s
) s
WHERE rnk = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT nr, pos, '2' AS src FROM bar
;
```

The innermost subquery unions rows from `foo` and `foobar`. The middle-tier subquery ranks `nr` values depending on the source table that provided them:

- rows from `foobar` are ranked as `1` if the corresponding `nr` values are not found in `foo`;
- otherwise it's `foo` rows that get ranked as `1`.

The ranked result set is filtered on `rnk = 1` and then unioned with the `bar` table (which, I understand, is returned unconditionally).

Comment: Hey thank you so much, this seems to work pretty well. And is exactly what I was searching for. Your example is pretty close to what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `where` clause to the last `select` to make it return results *only if* the first two queries had no results. See updated query below:

```
select nr, pos, '1' from foo
union all
select nr, pos, '2' from bar
union all
select nr, pos, '3' from foobar fb
 where not exists (select 1 from foo f where fb.nr = f.nr)
   and not exists (select 1 from bar b where fb.nr = b.nr)
```

Comment: Is there any way to refer the first result set from "foo" in the third querie ? So that I dont have to select from foo again ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but you need to use the union to achieve your requirement, however I thhink you can get rid of `select * from` because it is redundant, you just need the three selects. See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e81c0, to see the above code in action.

Comment: another note, `union all` is not necessary, because you differentiate rows from three tables already by having `1`, `2` and `3`, respectively, added to row from the three tables, you can simply use `union`.

Comment: Those NOT EXISTS clauses simply check whether the other tables are empty, not whether the `nr` value in `foobar` appears in those tables.

Comment: Using UNION ALL is a semi-justifiable performance hack.  Plain UNION does duplicate elimination.  A good optimizer would note that the constants mean there is no duplicate elimination, but writing UNION ALL doesn't give the optimizer a chance to get it wrong.

Comment: when you said `first querie` in your question I assumed you mean to say `first queries`, right? and not `first query`. If not, just cross out the last line `and not exists (select 1 from bar b where fb.nr = b.nr)`

Answer (score 1):

maybe a trick like this:

```
select distinct min(x), nr, pos from (
    select nr, pos, '1' as x from foo
    union all
    select nr, pos, '2' from bar
    union all
    select nr, pos, '3' from foobar
)
group by nr, pos
```

Comment: Interesting thought.  I suspect it won't meet the requirement because the `pos` value for `nr` in `foo` might well be different from the `pos` value for the same `nr` in `bar` (and from the `pos` value for the same `nr` in `foobar`), so all three rows would appear in the output if the three `pos` values are different.

Comment: well, not to beat it to death - but then maybe make a static column in each suquery that simply contains the 1,2,and 3

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT nr, pos, '1' AS code FROM foo
        UNION ALL
        SELECT nr, pos, '2' AS code FROM bar
        UNION ALL
        SELECT nr, pos, '3' AS code
          FROM foobar
         WHERE nr NOT IN (SELECT nr FROM foo)
       )
```

You can extend that treatment so the items from `bar` are not selected unless they are not listed in `foo`, and so that the items in `foobar` are not selected unless they are not listed in either `foo` or `bar`.  Clearly, you can choose a name other than `code` (perhaps `source`) as the column name for the numeric value, but you should provide a name for it.